# Autostarting a mono application

Tags: mono

I have been trying to get my mono form application to autostart with the GUI and I have tried lots of methods shown on other threads but it just won't work.

I manually run a .sh script by double clicking on the file to run my mono application which has this command:

```
sudo mono /home/pi/Test/monoApp.exe
```

I tried `xinitrc`, `LXDE-pi`, `crontab`, `rc.local` but they didn't work.

Comment: If it works from the command line but not from crontab that indicates a path problem.  Use `sudo which mono` to find the full path to mono and try using that full path in your scripts or crontab.

Comment: I changed the `mono` to `/usr/bin/mono` but nothing changed.
The .sh file launches the application both with `mono` and `/usr/bin/mono` when double clicking.
Can I launch the mono application by a python script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: create a `start.sh` file like this:

```
cd /home/pi/Test
mono monoApp.exe
```

Second: make this file executable

```
chmod +x start.sh
```

Third: setup crontab on startup

```
crontab -e
```

and add reboot file:

```
@reboot /home/pi/start.sh
```

on bottom, save and exit, reboot

Comment: Thanks for the info, I did as you told but nothing happens when I reboot the system.

Comment: Try to check if your file are run on startup, i.e. insert `mkdir something` on top and reboot, so you can find this `dir`, if you don't find it the problem is on crontab that cannot run your file, if you find it, the problem is inside the file

Comment: mkdir command works both from the script and from the crontab @reboot. 
I think the problem is really about the mono. Thank you for your extensive help and suggestions.

Comment: Do not forget to add `#!/bin/bash` on top of your start.sh script