# Raspberry pi python opencv error, gtk-warning cannot open display

Tags: python, opencv

I am running a python program from raspberry pi, which running this as text console mode. In normal desktop mode my program working, but when in text console mode, it says that

```
gtk-warning cannot open display
```

I want to run my program as autostart but it is not working. 
what is the solution??

Comment: To setup an autostart launcher, check [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69794/autostarting-a-mono-application/69797#69797)

Comment: most if not all gtk programs will require a desktop environment. Which is why it does not work from the command line but does from a terminal window. You need to launch your program using a method which does not run until the desktop is loaded, and you should probably boot to the desktop by default in that case.

Comment: so , opening an image using python from command line is not possible?

Comment: This solved it for me: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=80848. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me.
Open a terminal (not in super user mode), write: gksudo and when a windows open write "lxterminal" from root. Then a new terminal will open and from there run your program.

Good luck!