# How to run VNC Server automatically at boot?

Tags: raspbian, vnc

I'm using VNC Viewer in Windows to control the Raspberry Pi without screen but I need to get into the Raspberry Pi first by using putty software and then write the command code:

```
 $ vncserver
```

to create a server to be able to control the Pi with the VNC Viewer.

How can I run this automatically without code writing, how to configure it?

Comment: something like [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69794/autostarting-a-mono-application/69797#69797), into `start.sh` file insert your command

Comment: Which VNC Viewer? `RealVnc` is incompatible with most viewers. Do you intend to boot the Pi to GUI; if not `tightvncserver` is a better option, but setting either up on a headless system is non-trivial.

Comment: Here is the old way.  Not sure if it is still necessary.  https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-lesson-7-remote-control-with-vnc/running-vncserver-at-startup

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply enable the VNC server using `raspi-config`, and it will be started automatically during boot. Make sure to also set "boot to desktop", so that there's a GUI running to use with VNC. And use the official VNC client on Windows.

I'm doing this on a regular basis when I'm preparing new OS images for new projects: flash Raspbian image, create ssh file on boot partition, then headless boot, ssh into the Pi. Next, set hostname, change password, enable VNC. Reboot. Direct my VNC client (Android, Windows, ...) to the Pi using its newly set hostname (and correct domain for my home router).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RealVNC server provided by default with the Raspberry Pi OS, but you might face some issues.

In case you want to use **tightvncserver** and you want that to start at bootup, you can add these lines at the end of the .bashrc file.

```
sudo killall vncserver
vncserver -Authentication VncAuth :1
```

This is also sets the Authentication mode as VncAuth.

Comment: What issues might you face with the default server?